# How do I get the host name in Google App Engine on Custom Domain?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

On Google App Engine / webapp2, I use self.request.host to which works most of the time but occasionally doesn't use the custom domain.

```
http://%s % self.request.host  # sometimes returns ver.proj.appspot.com instead of mydomain.com
```

I found this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#getting_the_application_hostname but I don't always want the default version, I want the version if it's not the custom domain.

Answer (score -1):

self.request.host always returns the requests hostname used if it returns the ver.proj.appspot.com it has been requested with that URL.